# Retrieving radio button values from a PHP Session

Tags: php, session, cookies, radio-button

What I want to do is click on radio buttons on one page, and have it remember your choices for the other page. I have already done this for text, but obviously text is a little easier to remember and display than radio button option chosen. Or at least it is to me. Here is my code on page one that saves the variable:

```
        $_SESSION['fuel'] = $FUEL;
        $_SESSION['transmission'] = $TRANSMISSION;
        $_SESSION['engines'] = $ENGINES;
        $_DOORS['doors'] = $DOORS;
```

So the values of the form below are saved in the variables above. These are both on the same page. Now I would like to display these choices on another page, very similar to this one. Although if it is more complicated than I think it may be then I wont have time to do it.

Thanks for your help. **SOLVED**

Comment: Is this correct: You can save the radiobutton's state, but you don't know how to get it back?

Answer (score 5):

This is what you have to do:

1. start the session
2. get the selected value from post data
3. store the retrieved data into session for later use
4. compare the retrieved value with the radio value to set the "checked" attribute

---

```
<?php
session_start();
//set initial value
$transmission = "";
//get value from post data and store into session
if (isset($_POST['transmission'])){
    $_SESSION['transmission'] = $_POST['transmission'];
}
//get back from session
if (isset($_SESSION['transmission'])){
    $transmission = $_SESSION['transmission'];
}
//display selected value
?>
<form action="" method="post" onclick="this.submit()">
    Manual:<input <?php if ($transmission=='Manual'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" value="Manual" name="transmission"><br>
    Automatic:<input <?php if ($transmission=='Automatic'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" value="Automatic" name="transmission"><br>
    Semi-Auto:<input <?php if ($transmission=='Semi-Auto'){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="radio" value="Semi-Auto" name="transmission"><br>
</form>

<br><br>Selected Value: <?php echo $transmission; ?>
```

In this example the value is stored into session and then retrieved from session, so this will work on another page too.

Answer (score 0):

you could just start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

on your other page/php-file and then get your values with `$_SESSION['transmission']` etc..
but this only works when you first saved the data in your current php-file

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like
`<input type="radio" value="1" name="enginesize"<?php if(isset($_SESSION['enginesize'])) echo 'checked="checked"';?>` />

Comment: The form on the other page is already in php. So this line is not compatible very well with it. It gives me errors about "" marks.

Comment: You have a ' before checked but you dont close it. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, the "door"-variable will hold the value the user chosen, for instance 2. I assume you save that to a $_SESSION-variable.

```
$curr_doors = $_SESSION['doors'];
```

Now you have to use this to compare with radio button you want to set to checked, for instance:

```
printf ("2:<input type=radio value='2' name='doors' %s>\n",$cur_doors == 2 ?"checked":"");
printf ("3:<input type=radio value='2' name='doors' %s>\n",$cur_doors == 3 ?"checked":"");
printf ("4:<input type=radio value='2' name='doors' %s>\n",$cur_doors == 4 ?"checked":"");
printf ("5:<input type=radio value='2' name='doors' %s>\n",$cur_doors == 5 ?"checked":"");
```